# How to output file with all overlaps between two Shapefiles - Neighborhood/Zip Codes

Tags: shapefile, intersection, shapely, intersect

I have a pretty specific problem I would like help with.

I have two shapefiles:

neighborhoods from https://www.zillow.com/howto/api/neighborhood-boundaries.htm

zip codes from the census bureau: https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/cbf/cbf_zcta.html

The end result I would ideally like to achieve is this: a csv with each neighborhood in a specific file from Zillow (let's say we use the NY file) along with all zip codes from the second shapefile that overlap with that neighborhood.

For example:

[image: example]

Essentially what I would like to achieve is https://www.health.ny.gov/statistics/cancer/registry/appendix/neighborhoods.htm

but for all other major cities in the USA, using the Zillow mapping.

Seems like the way to approach this is using Python with Shapely/Fiona, but wondering if there is an elegant solution.

Comment: I suspect this will get closed as "too broad" because there are several things that need to be worked out, but my advice is to try intersecting your files, review the output, then come up with a method to loop through the records and organize them into the format you want. Come back with specific questions that you've tried and failed to answer.